# The db connection throws error in model unit test without explicit invoking

Tags: jestjs

I am doing unit test on nodejs 12.x jest 25 app. When the unit test is started with `npm test`, at the end it throws an error about a startup file `db.js` which establishes db connection. Here is the db.js file:

```
const Sql = require("sequelize");
const db = new Sql('emps', 'postgres', `${process.env.DB_PASSWORD}`, {
    host: 'localhost',
    dialect: 'postgres',
    port:5432,
} );

db
    .authenticate()  //<<<====this line causes the error 
    .then(() => {
        console.log('DB connection has been established successfully.');

    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.error('Unable to connect to the database:', err);
    });

module.exports = db;
```

Here is the error at the end of jest unit test:

```
  console.error startup/db.js:32
    Unable to connect to the database: ConnectionError [SequelizeConnectionError]: password authentication failed for user "postgres"
        at C:\D\code\js\emps_bbone\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\postgres\connection-manager.js:182:24
        at Connection.connectingErrorHandler (C:\D\code\js\emps_bbone\node_modules\pg\lib\client.js:194:14)
        at Connection.emit (events.js:311:20)
        at Socket.<anonymous> (C:\D\code\js\emps_bbone\node_modules\pg\lib\connection.js:134:12)
        at Socket.emit (events.js:311:20)
        at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:294:12)
        at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:275:11)
        at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:209:10)
        at TCP.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:186:23) {
      name: 'SequelizeConnectionError',
      parent: error: password authentication failed for user "postgres"
          at Connection.Object.<anonymous>.Connection.parseE (C:\D\code\js\emps_bbone\node_modules\pg\lib\connection.js:614:13)
          at Connection.Object.<anonymous>.Connection.parseMessage (C:\D\code\js\emps_bbone\node_modules\pg\lib\connection.js:413:19)
          at Socket.<anonymous> (C:\D\code\js\emps_bbone\node_modules\pg\lib\connection.js:129:22)
          at Socket.emit (events.js:311:20)
          at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:294:12)
          at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:275:11)
          at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:209:10)
          at TCP.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:186:23) {
        name: 'error',
        length: 163,
        severity: 'FATAL',
        code: '28P01',
        detail: undefined,
        hint: undefined,
        position: undefined,
        internalPosition: undefined,
        internalQuery: undefined,
        where: undefined,
        schema: undefined,
        table: undefined,
        column: undefined,
        dataType: undefined,
        constraint: undefined,
        file: 'd:\\pginstaller.auto\\postgres.windows-x64\\src\\backend\\libpq\\auth.c',
        line: '336',
        routine: 'auth_failed'
      },
      original: error: password authentication failed for user "postgres"
          at Connection.Object.<anonymous>.Connection.parseE (C:\D\code\js\emps_bbone\node_modules\pg\lib\connection.js:614:13)
          at Connection.Object.<anonymous>.Connection.parseMessage (C:\D\code\js\emps_bbone\node_modules\pg\lib\connection.js:413:19)
          at Socket.<anonymous> (C:\D\code\js\emps_bbone\node_modules\pg\lib\connection.js:129:22)
          at Socket.emit (events.js:311:20)
          at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:294:12)
          at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:275:11)
          at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:209:10)
          at TCP.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:186:23) {
        name: 'error',
        length: 163,
        severity: 'FATAL',
        code: '28P01',
        detail: undefined,
        hint: undefined,
        position: undefined,
        internalPosition: undefined,
        internalQuery: undefined,
        where: undefined,
        schema: undefined,
        table: undefined,
        column: undefined,
        dataType: undefined,
        constraint: undefined,
        file: 'd:\\pginstaller.auto\\postgres.windows-x64\\src\\backend\\libpq\\auth.c',
        line: '336',
        routine: 'auth_failed'
      }
    }
```

The `db.js` is required in app's `index.js`:

```
require("./startup/db");
```

Since my unit tests only test models (the db connection works fine. The problem is likely `process.env.DB_PASSWORD` didn't return a value somehow.), I don't quite understand how the db connection test jumps in by itself and throws error.

Comment: Some imported modules under test maybe refer or indirectly refer to the `db.js` file. When you require/import `db.js` file, the `db.authenticate()` will execute.Hardly to say based on the information you provide.

Comment: the `db.js` is required in app's `index.js`

Comment: If `process.env.DB_PASSWORD` is hard coded with value in db.js, then the error disappears.